# How to set single image and use to all the android devices?

Tags: android

I have to use a image in the top of my app as header image and the orientation is set horizontal as fix, as a newbie the problem that m facing is that I have to run the app to all major devices (240x320, 320x480, 480x800, 600x1024, 720x1280, 800x1280). So how can I fix?  Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which kind of image are you using for example? i mean just plain color background or else?

Comment: logo with gradient background color

Comment: Have you gone through these documents?  [screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 3):

@Abk Hello You should have to look in to this android developer link [Here is link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) 
and For Support on all devices you have to put your resource  images in 1.res/drawable for Default Images

Here is Your Structure of Resource Folder in android Project

```
  2.res/drawable-hdpi for high-density   // bitmap for high density
  3.res/drawable-hdpi-v5
  4.res/drawable-v9
  5.res/drawable-ldpi
  6.res/drawable-ldpi-v5
  7.res/drawable-ldpi-v9
  8.res/drawable-mdpi    // bitmap for medium density
  9.res/drawable-mdpi-v5
  10.res/drawable-mdpi-v9
  11.res/drawable-xhdpi    // bitmap for extra high density
```

Now For Layout Structure is below :

```
12.layout This Use For Default Layout Files  // layout for normal screen size ("default")
13.layout-land For Use in Landscape Mode
14 layout-large     // layout for large screen size
15.layout-large-long
16.layout-large-long-land
17.layout-large-notlong
18.layout-large-notlong-land
19.layout-ldpi
20.layout-normal-long
21.layout-normal-long-land
22.layout-normal-notlong
23.layout-normal-notlong-land
24.layout-small   // layout for small screen size
25.layout-small-land
26.layout-xlarge      // layout for extra large screen size
27.layout-xlarge-land   // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

If you are Still Not able to understand work with multiple Screen in android then look at this for Details Slide of android from Motorola.[Click here](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/working-with-multiple-screens/)

Answer (score 0):

Take your image in 3 size(small,big and medium), name should be same for each image(ex:- logo.png).
Copy that images in -
 1. Small image in res -> drawable-ldpi folder ,
 2. Big image in res -> drawable-hdpi folder and
 3. Medium image in res -> drawable-mdpi folder

It'll automatically adjust images according to the resolution of device.

You can also use 9patch images for the same.

Answer (score 0):

explore the 9 patch image format. Ideally you should be using multiple sets of images for hdpi, mdpi, ldpi,xhdpi for different sized screens.