# What resolution reference to consider for making images for android games?

Tags: android, resolution

I want to make a game which can work on all screen resolution and size. In order to begin making the game, what screen resolution should I consider for making graphics? I have seen that that the angry birds game has only a single image for all screen resolution, so what base resolution do they consider for making graphics? Next with that base what calculation do I have to do in order to scale those images for other resolution?

Comment: there's a SE site for game developpement: check it out, your question better belongs there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting multiple device in android then you need to use different image for your game need to use in android project.You can make your Android project Structure like below for all devices

Here is Your Structure of Resource Folder in android Project

```
 1.res/drawable for Default Images 
 2.res/drawable-hdpi for high-density   // bitmap for high density
 3.res/drawable-hdpi-v5
 4.res/drawable-v9
 5.res/drawable-ldpi
 6.res/drawable-ldpi-v5
 7.res/drawable-ldpi-v9
 8.res/drawable-mdpi    // bitmap for medium density
 9.res/drawable-mdpi-v5
 10.res/drawable-mdpi-v9
 11.res/drawable-xhdpi    // bitmap for extra high density
```

Now For Layout Structure is below :

```
   12.layout This Use For Default Layout Files  // layout for normal screen size ("default")
   13.layout-land For Use in Landscape Mode
   14 layout-large     // layout for large screen size
   15.layout-large-long
   16.layout-large-long-land
   17.layout-large-notlong
   18.layout-large-notlong-land
   19.layout-ldpi
   20.layout-normal-long
   21.layout-normal-long-land
   22.layout-normal-notlong
   23.layout-normal-notlong-land
   24.layout-small   // layout for small screen size
   25.layout-small-land
   26.layout-xlarge      // layout for extra large screen size
   27.layout-xlarge-land   // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

According to your requirement you can add image in res/drawable that used for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi same for layout file .Also you can refer this SO link .[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118125/how-to-set-single-image-and-use-to-all-the-android-devices/8118270#8118270)

Comment: Thanks Herry but when i see angry birds resource folder ...they have only single image and that works for any screen resolution...how do you think they do it?