# getDrawable from another resolution

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is it possible to get an image from `res/drawable-xxxdpi` if I use a ldpi device?
That is, `R.drawable.sunmsg` gives me the image link to current dpi.
I do not want to dublicate the resources from `res/drawable-xxxdpi` to `res/drawable`

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118125/how-to-set-single-image-and-use-to-all-the-android-devices

Comment: just put that image on that folder only...

Answer (score 1):

Android prefers scaling down larger sized images than scaling up lower resolution images (quality is given more priority than size/performance).

So if you're using an `mdpi` device, and you've let's say an image in `drawable-ldpi` and `drawable-xxxhdpi`, the xxxhdpi will be preferred over ldpi, i.e. it'll first search for the image starting from mdpi to xxxhdpi, until it finds the image. If not found, it'll start going to lower resolutions and as a last resort visit the `drawable` folder.

So in your case, **you basically don't need to do anything else**. Just keep the image in `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder and let android handle the rest.

But this is not advisable, because scaling down the higher density image  is equivalent to decoding a higher resolution image and then scaling it down, so it's going to be performance intensive, defeating the very purpose behind Android provisioning alternative configuration dependent resources.
Check [Size and density specific resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)

For a detailed documentation, check android's [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Answer (score 1):

### [I have a open source project I have Hosted in github here.](https://github.com/devrath/DeviceUiIdentifier)

.

1. Just run that project and that will tell you the device properties
   of the device and form a proper folder structure targeting a
   particular device
2. For Example I have a below folder structure for below device
   properties.
3. With those structure you can target a particular device.
4. There are multiple combinations you can make setting up your
   resource folder structure. - [*check here in android developers site*](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
5. [Check this link too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8118270/1083093).

.

### drawable-sw360dp-normal-hdpi

---

[image]

---

***Hope that helps !!***